# Extern inline functions must have the same address in all translation units. How the heck is that achieved?

Tags: c++, inline

According to the standard, extern inline functions must the same address in all translation units.

How is this achieved in the compiler? I mean when I'm compiling some translation unit, I have no idea what the other TU will be like. So how can I have the same address everywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's up to the implementation, but usually it's resolved by the linker. Each compiled translation unit will produce an object file containing a copy of the function, flagged in some way so that the linker knows that it should expect (and accept) duplicates. The linker will include one of them, discard the others, and resolve any references to the function.

Comment: What about libraries? Or am I going to far?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Static libraries are typically just a collection of object files, and so will probably contain multiple copies of the function, to be resolved later when linking into a program. Shared libraries are typically linked like a program, so multiple copies can be eliminated then.

Answer (score 4):

Simple strategy: every time such an `inline` function is defined, compile it to object time as if it were a normal function. Then, at link time, detect duplicate functions and remove them, leaving one copy of each. This is how C++ compilers used to work (also in the face of templates) some 10 years ago. Not sure how they do it nowadays.